# Return Subset of an array in form of a matrix [JAVA]

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Given an integer array (of length n), find and return all the subsets of input array.
So I have solved this problem but I'm not sure about the underlying concept at work here.

Here is the correct solution.

```
public static int[][] subsets(int input[]) {
              
        return subsets(input,0);
    }
    private static int[][] subsets(int input[], int index){
        if(index == input.length){
            int[][] a = new int[1][0];
            return a;
        }
        
        int[][] smallAns = subsets(input,index+1);
        int[][] ans = new int[2*(smallAns.length)][];
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < smallAns.length ; ++i){
            
                ans[i] = smallAns[i];
            
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < smallAns.length ; ++i){
            ans[i+smallAns.length] = new int[smallAns[i].length+1];
        }
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < smallAns.length ; ++i){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < ans[i+smallAns.length].length ; ++j){
                if(j == 0){
                    ans[i+smallAns.length][j] = input[index];
                }
                else{
                    ans[i+smallAns.length][j] = smallAns[i][j-1];
                }
            }
        }
        
        return ans;
    }
```

And this was my original solution:

```
    public static int[][] subsets(int input[]) {
              
        return subsets(input,0);
    }
    private static int[][] subsets(int input[], int index){
        if(index == input.length){
            int[][] a = new int[1][1];
            return a;
        }
        
        int[][] smallAns = subsets(input,index+1);
        int[][] ans = new int[2*(smallAns.length)][];
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < smallAns.length ; ++i){
            
                ans[i] = smallAns[i];
            
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < smallAns.length ; ++i){
            ans[i+smallAns.length] = new int[smallAns[i].length+1];
        }
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < smallAns.length ; ++i){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < ans[i+smallAns.length].length ; ++j){
                if(j == 0){
                    ans[i+smallAns.length][j] = input[index];
                }
                else{
                    ans[i+smallAns.length][j] = smallAns[i][j-1];
                }
            }
        }
        
        return ans;
    }
```

My original(wrong code the second one) code added 0 at the end of all the subsets. Like this
[image]

The correct code given at the beginning solves the problem. The only difference between those two codes is that first's base case returns a matrix of 1X1 (wrong one) and the second's base case returns a matrix of 1X0 (correct one) .But I'm curious about returning a 1X0 matrix at the base case. Could someone please explain how is not throwing nullPointerExceptions when i'm trying to access the length of column, etc.

Comment: A 1 x 0 matrix really is not so different from a 1 x 1 matrix.   In both cases `a.length == 1` and in both cases, `a[0]` is a valid, non-null reference to an `int[]`.  So in both cases it's safe to do `a[0].length` to ask for the number of columns: the answer will, not surprisingly, be 1 for the 1x1, and 0 for the 1x0.  Just don't try to see what `a[0][0]` is on a 1x0 matrix: you'll get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`!

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thank for the insight it's clear to me now. So the code works like this it takes the result of the recursion(smallAns (1X0 matrix in the first case)) copies that and also add a number to each entry of the result of recursion and combines them in a bigger matrix. My doubt is that what would it mean appending the selected number at the start of entry/entries of 1X0 matrix when it doesn't exist. Why didn't it OurOfIndex or NullPointer exceptions. The 1st code in my question is working I just don't know exactly how. Thanks.

Comment: Consider what happens when you copy an array 'a' of whatever length; 1) set counter `j=0`; 2) if `j >= a.length` STOP; 3) copy `a[j]` to its destination; 4) increment j (`++j`); and return to step 2.  If the array is of length 1, you'll hit step 3 just once before `j==a.length`, at which point you're done.  Now, what happens if `a.length == 0`? 1)  set count j=0; 2) if `j >= a.length` STOP.  `j==0`, `a.length == 0`, so already `j >= a.length`.  The loop never hits step (3), you never try to access even `a[0]`, so no `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the if statement in your code

```
if(index == input.length){
            int[][] a = new int[1][1];
            return a;
}
```

You initialise the variable `a` with a two-dimensional array (array of arrays), so to speak matrix with 1 row and 1 column. Since `a[0][0]` is not assigned any value it's given a default value for int data type `0`.

The variable `a` should be initialised with an array of array of 0 length instead

```
int[][] a = new int[1][0];
```